# Sublime Text 3 better file history

Tags: file, snapshot

I'm using Sublime to edit files on an FTP server,and I noticed that it doesn't save history of the changes as much as Eclipse does.
I had an incident where the file was dropped in an FTP transport and I had an empty file. crashing the whole website down.

Is there a way to increase the time span of file's history in Sublime 3?

Comment: I would not rely on such mechanisms for something as important as a website. Perhaps you should consider proper source control.

Comment: I only have an FTP connection.. Is there a way to make a local source control somehow?

Comment: Yes, try looking into git or other similar tools.